# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast make my apps crash

Tags: android-studio

I have plenty of this error in but in other pages and this error refused to show me the next page. Here's my error. This error "cannot be cast on" actually appear on more than one page. Is this error from my coding or database? Thanks in advance

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.prototype, PID: 5537
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.TaskaKemasNurSurya.ApplicationContext
        at com.example.TaskaKemasNurSurya.ModifyAttandance$3.onClick(ModifyAttandance.java:58)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

here's my code

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                DBAdapter dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(ModifyAttandance.this);
                ArrayList<AttendanceBean> attendanceBeanList=dbAdapter.getAllAttendanceByStudent();
                ((ApplicationContext)ModifyAttandance.this.getApplicationContext()).setAttendanceBeanList(attendanceBeanList);
                Intent intent = new Intent(ModifyAttandance.this,ViewAttendancePerStudentActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

And this from database

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DBAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Attendance";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String STUDENT_INFO_TABLE = "student_table";
    private static final String ATTENDANCE_SESSION_TABLE = "attendance_session_table";
    private static final String ATTENDANCE_TABLE = "attendance_table";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_STUDENT_MYKID = "student_mykid";
    private static final String KEY_STUDENT_NAME = "student_name";
    private static final String KEY_STUDENT_MO_NO = "student_mobilenumber";
    private static final String KEY_STUDENT_ADDRESS = "student_address";
    private static final String KEY_STUDENT_YEAR = "student_year";

    private static final String KEY_ATTENDANCE_SESSION_ID = "attendance_session_id";
    private static final String KEY_ATTENDANCE_SESSION_DATE = "attendance_session_date";
    private static final String KEY_ATTENDANCE_SESSION_YEAR = "attendance_session_year";

    private static final String KEY_SESSION_ID = "attendance_session_id";
    private static final String KEY_ATTENDANCE_STUDENT_MYKID = "attendance_student_mykid";
    private static final String KEY_ATTENDANCE_STATUS = "attendance_status";


    public DBAdapter(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String queryStudent="CREATE TABLE "+ STUDENT_INFO_TABLE +" (" +
                KEY_STUDENT_MYKID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_STUDENT_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_STUDENT_MO_NO + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_STUDENT_ADDRESS + " TEXT," +
                KEY_STUDENT_YEAR + " INTEGER " + ")";
        Log.d("queryStudent",queryStudent );

        String queryAttendanceSession="CREATE TABLE "+ ATTENDANCE_SESSION_TABLE +" (" +
                KEY_ATTENDANCE_SESSION_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_ATTENDANCE_SESSION_DATE + " DATE," +
                KEY_ATTENDANCE_SESSION_YEAR + " INTEGER" + ")";
        Log.d("queryAttendanceSession",queryAttendanceSession );

        String queryAttendance="CREATE TABLE "+ ATTENDANCE_TABLE +" (" +
                KEY_SESSION_ID + " INTEGER, " +
                KEY_ATTENDANCE_STUDENT_MYKID + " INTEGER, " +
                KEY_ATTENDANCE_STATUS + " TEXT " + ")";
        Log.d("queryAttendance",queryAttendance );

        try
        {
            db.execSQL(queryStudent);
            db.execSQL(queryAttendanceSession);
            db.execSQL(queryAttendance);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {

        String queryStudent="CREATE TABLE "+ STUDENT_INFO_TABLE +" (" +
                KEY_STUDENT_MYKID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_STUDENT_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_STUDENT_MO_NO + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_STUDENT_ADDRESS + " TEXT," +
                KEY_STUDENT_YEAR + " TEXT " + ")";
        Log.d("queryStudent",queryStudent );

        String queryAttendanceSession="CREATE TABLE "+ ATTENDANCE_SESSION_TABLE +" (" +
                KEY_ATTENDANCE_SESSION_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_ATTENDANCE_SESSION_DATE + " TEXT," +
                KEY_ATTENDANCE_SESSION_YEAR + " INTEGER" +")";
        Log.d("queryAttendanceSession",queryAttendanceSession );

        String queryAttendance="CREATE TABLE "+ ATTENDANCE_TABLE +" (" +
                KEY_SESSION_ID + " INTEGER, " +
                KEY_ATTENDANCE_STUDENT_MYKID + " INTEGER, " +
                KEY_ATTENDANCE_STATUS + " TEXT " + ")";
        Log.d("queryAttendance",queryAttendance );

        try
        {
            db.execSQL(queryStudent);
            db.execSQL(queryAttendanceSession);
            db.execSQL(queryAttendance);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void addStudent(StudentBean studentBean) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String query = "INSERT INTO student_table (student_name,student_mobilenumber,student_address,student_year) values ('"+
                studentBean.getStudent_name()+"', '"+
                studentBean.getStudent_mobilenumber()+"', '"+
                studentBean.getStudent_address()+"', '"+
                studentBean.getStudent_year()+"')";
        Log.d("query", query);
        db.execSQL(query);
        db.close();
    }
    public ArrayList<StudentBean> getAllStudent()
    {
        ArrayList<StudentBean> list = new ArrayList<StudentBean>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM student_table";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{
                StudentBean studentBean = new StudentBean();
                studentBean.setStudent_mykid(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                studentBean.setStudent_name(cursor.getString(1));
                studentBean.setStudent_mobilenumber(cursor.getString(2));
                studentBean.setStudent_address(cursor.getString(3));
                studentBean.setStudent_year(cursor.getString(4));
                list.add(studentBean);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return list;
    }
    public ArrayList<StudentBean> getAllStudentByBranchYear(String branch,String year)
    {
        ArrayList<StudentBean> list = new ArrayList<StudentBean>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM student_table where student_year='"+year+"'";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{
                StudentBean studentBean = new StudentBean();
                studentBean.setStudent_mykid(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                studentBean.setStudent_name(cursor.getString(1));
                studentBean.setStudent_mobilenumber(cursor.getString(2));
                studentBean.setStudent_address(cursor.getString(3));
                studentBean.setStudent_year(cursor.getString(4));
                list.add(studentBean);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return list;
    }
    public StudentBean getStudentByMykid(int studentMykid)
    {
        StudentBean studentBean = new StudentBean();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM student_table where student_id="+studentMykid;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{

                studentBean.setStudent_mykid(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                studentBean.setStudent_name(cursor.getString(1));
                studentBean.setStudent_mobilenumber(cursor.getString(2));
                studentBean.setStudent_address(cursor.getString(3));
                studentBean.setStudent_year(cursor.getString(4));

            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return studentBean;
    }
    public void deleteStudent(int studentMykid) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String query = "DELETE FROM student_table WHERE student_id="+studentMykid ;

        Log.d("query", query);
        db.execSQL(query);
        db.close();
    }

    //attendance session Table crud
    public int addAttendanceSession(AttendanceSessionBean attendanceSessionBean) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String query = "INSERT INTO attendance_session_table (attendance_session_year,attendance_session_date) values ('"+
                attendanceSessionBean.getAttendance_session_date()+"', '"+
                attendanceSessionBean.getAttendance_session_year()+"')";
        Log.d("query", query);
        db.execSQL(query);

        String query1= "select max(attendance_session_id) from attendance_session_table";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query1, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            int sessionId = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));

            return sessionId;
        }


        db.close();
        return 0;
    }

    public ArrayList<AttendanceSessionBean> getAllAttendanceSession()
    {
        ArrayList<AttendanceSessionBean> list = new ArrayList<AttendanceSessionBean>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM attendance_session_table";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{
                AttendanceSessionBean attendanceSessionBean = new AttendanceSessionBean();
                attendanceSessionBean.setAttendance_session_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                attendanceSessionBean.setAttendance_session_date(cursor.getString(1));
                attendanceSessionBean.setAttendance_session_year(cursor.getString(2));
                list.add(attendanceSessionBean);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return list;
    }

    public void deleteAttendanceSession(int attendanceSessionId) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String query = "DELETE FROM attendance_session_table WHERE attendance_session_id="+attendanceSessionId ;

        Log.d("query", query);
        db.execSQL(query);
        db.close();
    }
    //attendance crud
    public void addNewAttendance(AttendanceBean attendanceBean) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String query = "INSERT INTO attendance_table values ("+
                attendanceBean.getAttendance_session_id()+", "+
                attendanceBean.getAttendance_student_mykid()+", '"+
                attendanceBean.getAttendance_status()+"')";
        Log.d("query", query);
        db.execSQL(query);
        db.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<AttendanceBean> getAttendanceBySessionID(AttendanceSessionBean attendanceSessionBean)
    {
        int attendanceSessionId=0;
        ArrayList<AttendanceBean> list = new ArrayList<AttendanceBean>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM attendance_session_table where attendance_session_year='"+attendanceSessionBean.getAttendance_session_year()+"'" +
                " AND attendance_session_date='"+attendanceSessionBean.getAttendance_session_date();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{
                attendanceSessionId=(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        String query1="SELECT * FROM attendance_table where attendance_session_id=" + attendanceSessionId+" order by attendance_student_id";
        Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery(query1, null);
        if(cursor1.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{
                AttendanceBean attendanceBean = new AttendanceBean();
                attendanceBean.setAttendance_session_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor1.getString(0)));
                attendanceBean.setAttendance_student_mykid(Integer.parseInt(cursor1.getString(1)));
                attendanceBean.setAttendance_status(cursor1.getString(2));
                list.add(attendanceBean);

            }while(cursor1.moveToNext());
        }
        return list;
    }

    public ArrayList<AttendanceBean> getTotalAttendanceBySessionID(AttendanceSessionBean attendanceSessionBean)
    {
        int attendanceSessionId=0;
        ArrayList<AttendanceBean> list = new ArrayList<AttendanceBean>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM attendance_session_table where attendance_session_year='"+"'";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{
                attendanceSessionId=(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));

                String query1="SELECT * FROM attendance_table where attendance_session_id=" + attendanceSessionId+" order by attendance_student_id";
                Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery(query1, null);
                if(cursor1.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do{
                        AttendanceBean attendanceBean = new AttendanceBean();
                        attendanceBean.setAttendance_session_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor1.getString(0)));
                        attendanceBean.setAttendance_student_mykid(Integer.parseInt(cursor1.getString(1)));
                        attendanceBean.setAttendance_status(cursor1.getString(2));
                        list.add(attendanceBean);

                    }while(cursor1.moveToNext());
                }

                AttendanceBean attendanceBean = new AttendanceBean();
                attendanceBean.setAttendance_session_id(0);
                attendanceBean.setAttendance_status("Date : " + cursor.getString(4));
                list.add(attendanceBean);

            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }


        return list;
    }

    public ArrayList<AttendanceBean> getAllAttendanceByStudent()
    {
        ArrayList<AttendanceBean> list = new ArrayList<AttendanceBean>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT attendance_student_mykid,count(*) FROM attendance_table where attendance_status='P' group by attendance_student_mykid";

        Log.d("query", query);

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);



        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{
                Log.d("studentId","studentId:"+cursor.getString(0)+", Count:"+cursor.getString(1));
                AttendanceBean attendanceBean = new AttendanceBean();
                attendanceBean.setAttendance_student_mykid(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                attendanceBean.setAttendance_session_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
                list.add(attendanceBean);

            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return list;
    }

    /*public ArrayList<AttendanceBean> getAllAttendanceBySessionID(int sessionId)
    {
        ArrayList<AttendanceBean> list = new ArrayList<AttendanceBean>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM attendance_table where attendance_session_id=" + sessionId;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if(!cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{
                AttendanceBean attendanceBean = new AttendanceBean();
                attendanceBean.setAttendance_session_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                attendanceBean.setAttendance_student_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
                attendanceBean.setAttendance_status(cursor.getString(2));
                list.add(attendanceBean);

            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return list;
    }*/




    // Creating Tables
    /*@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_User_Info_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_INFO_USER + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT, "+ " +KEY_MO_NO +" TEXT, "
                +KEY_EMAIL +" TEXT, " +KEY_USERNAME +" TEXT, " + KEY_PASSWORD +" TEXT " + ")";

        Log.d("rupali",CREATE_User_Info_TABLE );
        db.execSQL(CREATE_User_Info_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_INFO_USER);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

     *//**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     *//*



    void addUserInfo(UserInfo userinfo) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, userinfo.getUser_Firstname()); //  Name
        values.put(KEY_LASTNAME, userinfo.getUser_Lastname()); //  Name
        values.put(KEY_MO_NO, userinfo.getUser_MobileNo()); // Contact Phone
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, userinfo.getUser_EmailId());
        values.put(KEY_USERNAME, userinfo.getUser_Username());
        values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, userinfo.getUser_Password());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_INFO_USER, null, values);
        //2nd argument is String containing nullColumnHack
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }


    // Getting single contact
    UserInfo getUserInfo(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_INFO_USER, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                KEY_FIRSTNAME, KEY_LASTNAME,KEY_MO_NO,  KEY_EMAIL, KEY_USERNAME, KEY_PASSWORD }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        UserInfo userinfo = new UserInfo(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),cursor.getString(6));
        // return contact
                return userinfo;
    }

    public UserInfo validateUser(String username, String password)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "Select * from User_Info_Table WHERE User_Username='"+ username +"' AND User_Password='"+password+"'";
        Log.d("Rupali", "Login QUERY:" + query);

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);


        if(!cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            Log.d("Rupali", "cursor is null.. returing NULL");
            return null;
        }
        Log.d("Rupali", "cursor is NOT null.. we got user data...");


        UserInfo userinfo = new UserInfo(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),cursor.getString(6));

        return userinfo;
    }

    // Updating single contact
    public int updateUserPassword(UserInfo userinfo) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, userinfo.getUser_Password());


        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_INFO_USER, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(userinfo.getUser_id()) });
    }

    public int updateUserContact(UserInfo userinfo) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_MO_NO, userinfo.getUser_MobileNo());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, userinfo.getUser_EmailId());


        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_INFO_USER, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(userinfo.getUser_id()) });
    }


    //veiw details

    public UserInfo viewUserInfo(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String query = "Select * from User_Info_Table WHERE id='"+id+"'";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if(!cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            Log.d("Rupali", "cursor is null.. returing NULL");
            return null;
        }
        Log.d("Rupali", "cursor is NOT null.. we got user data...");

        UserInfo userinfo = new UserInfo(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),cursor.getString(6));
        // return contact
        return userinfo;
    }



     // Getting All users
    public List<UserInfo> getAllUserInfo() {
        List<UserInfo> userinfolist = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_INFO_USER;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                UserInfo userinfo=new UserInfo();

                userinfo.setUser_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                userinfo.setUser_Lastname(cursor.getString(2));
                userinfo.setUser_Username(cursor.getString(5));
                userinfo.setUser_Firstname(cursor.getString(1));



                // Adding contact to list
                userinfolist.add(userinfo);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return userinfolist;
    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteUser(UserInfo userinfo) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_INFO_USER, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(userinfo.getUser_id()) });
        db.close();
    }
      */
}
```

and this from attendance Bean

```
public class AttendanceBean {

    private int attendance_session_id;
    private int attendance_student_mykid;
    private String attendance_status;

    public int getAttendance_session_id() {
        return attendance_session_id;
    }
    public void setAttendance_session_id(int attendance_session_id) {
        this.attendance_session_id = attendance_session_id;
    }
    public int getAttendance_student_mykid() {
        return attendance_student_mykid;
    }
    public void setAttendance_student_mykid(int attendance_student_id) {
        this.attendance_student_mykid = attendance_student_id;
    }
    public String getAttendance_status() {
        return attendance_status;
    }
    public void setAttendance_status(String attendance_status) {
        this.attendance_status = attendance_status;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I asume your `onClick()` method is inside `ModifyAttandance` class. The problem is your casting:

```
((ApplicationContext)ModifyAttandance.this.getApplicationContext()).setAttendanceBeanList(attendanceBeanList);
```

Give it a try like this.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

    DBAdapter dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
    ArrayList<AttendanceBean> attendanceBeanList=dbAdapter.getAllAttendanceByStudent();
    setAttendanceBeanList(attendanceBeanList);
    Intent intent = new Intent(ModifyAttandance.this,ViewAttendancePerStudentActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
});
```

Comment: i tried but it said "Cannot resolve method 'setAttendanceBeanList(java.util.ArrayList<com.example.TaskaKemasNurSurya.AttendanceBean>)'"

Comment: Where do you have located your `setAttendanceBeanList` method? Can you edit your post and add the class with this method?

Comment: you can refer to attendance Bean